# How to use boost::serialization between x86 and x64 platforms

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, compatibility, 32bit-64bit

I have a program that runs as 64 bit application under Windows. I want the same program to work as 32 bit application. It compiles, links and runs, but I cannot read the files which I stored with the 64 bit application in the 32 bit application. I use boost::serialization with binary archives for writing and reading from files.

The software has already been released to a client. The client should be able to read the files that have been stored by the 64 bit application with the 32 bit application. Is this possible? How? Any expenriences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could write a 64 bit application that converts binary archives to xml archives. these you could probably read with a 32 bit application and convert to a format of your choice.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [protable binary archive](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/serialization/doc/todo.html#portablebinaryarchives).

Comment: But that does not work for the old files I saved using the standard binary archive, does it? It seems to be a good alternative though, if the old files cannot be loaded by the 32 bit application at all.